# Copia de pastas com espaço CMD

Tags: cmd

Óla gostaria de saber como faço para copiar uma pasta nomeada com espaço no CMD, porém o comando esta dentro de aspas duplas e ele não aceita outra aspas duplas dentro, por exemplo, ja tentei das seguintes formas e nenhuma delas deu certo, alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado

```
@echo off
SET var=C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\'programs teste'\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip
runas /user:%usuario% "CMD /C title NETProxy & copy %var% C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ /y & start c:\Users\Public\Desktop\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" > null

@echo off
SET var=C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\"programs teste"\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip
runas /user:%usuario% "CMD /C title NETProxy & copy %var% C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ /y & start c:\Users\Public\Desktop\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" > null

@echo off
SET var="C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\programs teste\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip"
runas /user:%usuario% "CMD /C title NETProxy & copy %var% C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ /y & start c:\Users\Public\Desktop\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" > null

@echo off
runas /user:%usuario% "CMD /C title NETProxy & copy "C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\'programs teste'\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ /y & start c:\Users\Public\Desktop\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" > null

@echo off
runas /user:%usuario% "CMD /C title NETProxy & copy "C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\"programs teste"\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ /y & start c:\Users\Public\Desktop\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" > null

@echo off
runas /user:%usuario% "CMD /C title NETProxy & copy "C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\programs teste\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" C:\Users\Public\Desktop\ /y & start c:\Users\Public\Desktop\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip" > null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toda pasta / arquivo pelo prompt de comando tem um nome curto, que sempre é 6 'letras' + '~' + numero pela ordem alfabética.

Exemplo:

*Pastas:*

```
Program Files
Program Files (x86)
```

*No CMD, elas serão respectivamente:*

```
Progra~1
Progra~2
```

**Logo, o caminho da sua pasta será:**

```
C:\Users\MIKAEL\Downloads\progra~1\cpu-z_1.80-en.zip
```

> Para listar todos os diretórios de uma pasta, mostrando os nomes curtos, no prompt de comando digite:

```
dir /X
```

Resultado:

```
14/07/2017  23:44    <DIR>                       Intel
22/08/2013  13:22    <DIR>                       PerfLogs
03/08/2017  22:09    <DIR>          PLATAF~1     PlataformaTISS
03/11/2017  19:39    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
15/11/2017  22:56    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
14/07/2017  22:19                 0              Recovery.txt
14/07/2017  23:29    <DIR>                       Users
08/01/2018  23:50    <DIR>                       Windows
15/10/2017  23:29    <DIR>                       Xamarin
02/09/2017  02:10    <DIR>                       xampp
```

Comment: nossa cara funcionou, muitíssimo OBRIGADO :)